# Android Tablet - hello world

Tags: android, tablet

I have a samsung galaxy tab 10.1 3G+WiFi version with Android 3.2. I would like to write some program for the tablet version, but I have some problem with Android emulator. Here is my setting as follow:
1) Eclipse SDK ver 3.7.1
2) Java JDK ver 1.6.0_25
3) Android Development Toolkit ver 16.0.1.v201112120204-238534
4) Dalvik Debug Monitor Service ver 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534

Project Properties for BA3TPHello (the name of project is BA3TPHello)
1) Project Build Target -> Abdroid 3.1

AVD detail:

> ```
> Target: Android 3.1 (API level 12) 
> Skin : WXGA 
> SD Card: 256M
> hw.lcd.density : 160 
> hw.keyboard.lid : no 
> vm.heapSize: 48 
> hw.ramSize: 512
> ```

```
package com.apress.ba3tp.hello;
import com.apress.ba3tp.hello.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Hello extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void clickHello(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

I have "Force Close" error on the emulator. Here is some log from Console.

```
[2012-02-12 12:55:24 - BA3TPHello] Android Launch!
[2012-02-12 12:55:24 - BA3TPHello] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-12 12:55:24 - BA3TPHello] Performing hello.hello activity launch
[2012-02-12 12:55:24 - BA3TPHello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'HoneyComb'
[2012-02-12 12:55:24 - BA3TPHello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'HoneyComb'
[2012-02-12 12:55:30 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-02-12 12:55:30 - BA3TPHello] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-12 12:55:30 - BA3TPHello] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-02-12 12:56:53 - BA3TPHello] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-12 12:56:53 - BA3TPHello] Uploading BA3TPHello.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-12 12:56:53 - BA3TPHello] Installing BA3TPHello.apk...
[2012-02-12 12:58:08 - BA3TPHello] Success!
[2012-02-12 12:58:09 - BA3TPHello] Starting activity hello.hello on device emulator-5554
[2012-02-12 12:58:11 - BA3TPHello] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.apress.ba3tp.hello/hello.hello }
```

And I've log from LogCat. How do I post attach file?
I don't know how to check the log from LogCat.

LogCat -> http://www.mediafire.com/?28r79b5y432qd2z

AndroidManifest.xml -> http://www.mediafire.com/?9m1bkgyzk949hsn

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you're seeing? We have your setup, but we don't know what's wrong :)

Comment: Thank for reply, Here is some log from Console

Comment: Thank for reply, I'm new to this forum. My problem is I have "Force close" on emulator. I knew that pressing "run" button will solve the problem but not for my case. thank

Comment: you need to look at logcat, to see the errors created on the device. just paste in the bit of the log where it breaks.

Comment: Thank, Matthew, Since the comment is limited to 583 characters, so I post in my original post, please check it above.

Comment: @paksoft: Logcat doesnt have any exceptions/errors 1.What are you expecting this code to do? 2.What problem you are facing? Can you edit the post and add AndroidManifest.xml as well?

Comment: Looks like there is some problem in your Manifest.xml as this line says  "Starting activity hello.hello on device emulator-5554". Where Hello is your Class name (Remember case sensitive) and Package is "com.apress.ba3tp.hello". Why does it looking for hello.hello ? Manifest please.

Comment: please provide your manifest and xml file . Where you have mentioned clickHello() function?

Comment: @Dark Rider, I've upload AndroidManifest.xml, My problem is the program cannot run, it says "Force Close". please check my original post, thanks,

Comment: Ok from your Manifest Change this Line android:name="hello.hello" to android:name=".Hello"

Comment: Force close problem -> http://www.mediafire.com/?sw0knpe1k2g3s65

Comment: Have you changed as suggested above? remember case sensitive.. >>hello -> Hello

Comment: Yes, I have but still loading emulator.

Comment: As advice you dont need to close and restart emulator for every deployement change, Keep the emulator up and running and then from your project run as android application.

Comment: It's working. thank you. But can you please explain about the problem I just run the example code from the book. [ http://www.apress.com/9781430237839 ] , I guess it should be this line " public class Hello extends Activity ". thanks